# understanding of operator precedence in the php

Tags: php

Following is my code in php.

```
$sale = 200;
$sale = $sale - + 1;
echo $sale;
```

I don't understand why output of the variable is 199. can someone please help me understand the logic behind it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How else could that possibly be interpreted, besides as a syntax error?

Comment: This isn't PHP, this is basic 1st grade mathematics

Comment: This question points one more time that PHP is awesome

Comment: @MarkBaker in maths I never see this; there nobody writes a + behind a minus...

Comment: @Wooble There is no syntax error, [it works](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rnh-4gi)

Comment: I know it works. I mean that the only alternative to how it works would be for it to be an error; if there was no unary `+`, the `-` would be missing its right operand.

Comment: @bwoebi but you could, its same as in that example, nobody would write it that way, but you can if you want ;)

Comment: @bwoebi - you never learned about positive numbers and negative numbers? Wew! What do they teach kids in school these days.... no-one normally writes it, because it's implicit... but by definition any positive number is +n and any negative number is -n

Comment: I don't know answer but in learning and experimenting you can do these things. But in real application, use brackets, or easy way. Try to follow KISS (keep it simple and stupid) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: @MarkBaker I mean: nobody writes `a - + b` or `a - (+ b)`, only `a + (- b)` or `a + -b`...

Comment: I know usually no one write such kind of code. But I am preparing for zend examinations. such kind of questions are asked in it.

Comment: This user usually writes reasonable questions...I'm guessing this is spam attempt from his colleagues, it's just too stupid for words. LOL at people answering it.

Comment: Use php debugger to know exact answer.

Comment: Basic math `+-` = `-`  `a + (-b)` => `a-b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
+ 1
```

is the positive integer `1`.

So it's interpreted as:

```
$sale = $sale - (+ 1);
// ===
$sale = $sale - 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @bwoebi, such questions are asked in zend certification exam. I was going through series of such questions.

Comment: @krunalshah I thought Zend certifies the PHP knowhow, not the logic...

Comment: yes but in some mockup papers I found such type of questions. so, need to get answer for it.

Comment: - doesn't come first! Php will take - and +, and since + comes first, + will take precdence over -:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php  The answer may be the same, but you need to know your precedence!

Comment: thanks @PhilCross. now getting the things.

Comment: @PhilCross it has nothing with operator precedence, its about mathematical resolving of operators, imho, how would you explain $sale - + - + 1;

Answer (score 0):

It's because +1 is a valid number.

So you do:

```
$sale = $sale - (+ 1);
```

and `+1` equals `1`.

The number sign is more important than sum/substract operators (+ and -)